# Android BLE get raw values from onCharacteristicChanged

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, binary-data, uint8array

Is there a way to get the `characteristic.value` in `onCharacteristicChanged` as a byteArray of size 64 in binary?

I successfully subscribe to a notify-characteristic of a BLE Service (in Android/Kotlin). I know, that the data sent by the Bluetooth device consists of 64 bits (a UInt32 followed by two UInt16's). However, when I look at the value in `onCharacteristicChanged`, I get a byteArray of size 8 with values like this: [-120, -106, -57, 0, -1, -1, 20, 0]
It should be a byteArray of size 64 with 0's and 1's. How can I achieve that?

This is the code that gives me the byteArray of size 8:

```
override fun onCharacteristicChanged(gatt: BluetoothGatt, characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic) {
        with(characteristic) {
                Log.d(TAG, "value: ${Arrays.toString(value)}") //[-120, -106, -57, 0, -1, -1, 20, 0]
                Log.d(TAG,"value.size: ${value.size}") //8
        }
}
```

Comment: each of the bytes consists of 8 bits. There you have your 0's and 1's

Comment: So I have to convert each of the integers to an 8-bit representation and this is the raw output of the bluetooth device?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53929025/how-to-get-an-unsigned-integer-from-a-byte-array-in-kotlin-jvm maybe try this